# given OGF of some sequence, provide a closed form expression for the sequence.

Tags: generating-functions

If we have OGF(Ordinary Generating Function) of $d_{n}$:

$d(x)=\frac{1}{4-2x+x^2}$

How to get a closed form expression for $d_{n}$?

Comment: There are many questions on this site about exactly this... a search should find a few.

Comment: I am thinking about can we get a answer without complex numbers?

Comment: Sure, in real polynomials the complex roots occur in conjugates and cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone who may need this.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(x) &= (4-2x+x^2)^{-1} \\
  &= \frac{1}{(\alpha -x)(\beta -x)}\\
     &= \frac{A}{\alpha -x} + \frac{B}{\beta -x}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
We can determine that :
\begin{equation*}
A(\beta -x) + B(\alpha -x) = 1
\end{equation*}
So, we have:
\begin{equation*}
A = \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha},\\
B = \frac{1}{\alpha - \beta}
\end{equation*}
Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 d(x) &= \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} (\frac{1}{\alpha - x} - \frac{1}{\beta - x})\\
      &= \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} (\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{\alpha}} - \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{\beta}}) 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Since we know:
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{1}{1-cx} = \sum_{n \geq 0} c^n x^n
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation}
[x^n]d(x) = \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} (\frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1}}- \frac{1}{\beta^{n+1}})
\end{equation}
and we can substitute $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as we know:
\begin{equation*}
\alpha = 1 - \sqrt{3} i , \beta = 1 + \sqrt{3} i
\end{equation*}
And (2) can be simplified as following:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
[x^n]d(x) &= \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} (\frac{1}{\alpha^{n+1}}- \frac{1}{\beta^{n+1}})\\
    &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}i}(\frac{1}{ (1 - \sqrt{3} i)^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{ (1 + \sqrt{3} i)^{n+1}})\\
          &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}i} \frac{ (1 + \sqrt{3} i)^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{3} i)^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} \\
          &= \frac{1}{2^{n+2} \sqrt{3}i} [(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^{n+1} - (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i)^{n+1}] \\
          &= \frac{1}{2^{n+2} \sqrt{3}i} [(\cos\frac{\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{\pi}{3} )^{n+1} - (\cos\frac{-\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{-\pi}{3} )^{n+1}] \\
          &= \frac{1}{2^{n+2} \sqrt{3}i} \{exp[\frac{(n+1)\pi i}{3}] - exp[-\frac{(n+1)\pi i}{3}]\} \\
          &= \frac{1}{2^{n+2} \sqrt{3}i} [(\cos\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{(n+1)\pi}{3} ) - (\cos\frac{-(n+1)\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{-(n+1)\pi}{3} )]\\
          &= \frac{1}{2^{n+2} \sqrt{3}i} [2i\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3}] \\
          &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3 \cdot 2^{n+1}} \sin[\frac{(n+1)}{3} \pi]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}